# Set Icons Folder For Movie Collection Automatically using command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

i have a movie collection contains 150+ movies in their own folder.i want to set their movie poster as its icon.cant do it manually for all the folders,is there any command prompt script to do it.

the script must support folder with spaces.
thank you

Comment: Adapt batch code posted at [Batch Filename reading for Icons (Desktop.ini)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27745109/3074564) to your folder structure and icon files.

Answer (score 0):

No but custom icons are specified in a hidden file called desktop.ini in each customised folder. A desktop.ini file is only read if the folder has either System or Read Only attributes set.

This is a desktop.ini

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Users\User\Documents\Pictures\New Folder\Internet Explorer Wallpaper (2).bmp,0
```