# How to write a BAT file that changes icons?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-11

I am adapting my PC (Windows 11) to work with Google Workspace. I pinned folders created on Google Drive in File Explorer (Documents, Pictures...), which I keep locally on the drive and synchronizes with the cloud. Unfortunately, every time the system boots, the folder icons reset. I'm planning to create a BAT file that will run on system startup and set the pinned folder icons accordingly. For example: for the folder "C:\Users\david\Mój dysk\Dokumenty" he set the system icon of the folder documents from "SHELL32.dll". Unfortunately, I don't know how to write such a script to a BAT file?

So far I've tried the code found on the internet:

```bash
echo [.ShellClassInfo] > C:\Users\david\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini
echo IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll >> C:\Users\david\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini
echo IconIndex=5 >> C:\Users\david\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not protect the space character with doublequotes? Change ```C:\Users\david\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini``` to ```"C:\Users\david\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini"```, or possibly better: ```"%UserProfile%\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini"```. Please also ensure that the script is saved using the same codepage as you have defined in your batch file, (using `chcp.com`). To learn more type `chcp /?` in a Command Prompt window, and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: See: [Batch file to attach icons to subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660866/) and [How to get file name of an icon file in a folder for creating/updating desktop.ini for folder(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279085/)

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my comments, here's a batch file example:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 1>NUL
@(Echo [.ShellClassInfo]
  Echo ConfirmFileOp=0
  Echo IconFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll
  Echo IconIndex=5
  Echo InfoTip=Google Drive Dokumenty.) 1>"%UserProfile%\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini"
@%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +H +S "%UserProfile%\Mój dysk\Dokumenty\desktop.ini"
```

Save the batch file using an editor which allows you to specify ANSI/DOS codepage `1252`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect, the folder indicated in the path does not change the icon

Comment: Prove it @DawidZapora. I cannot debug "the folder indicated in the path does not change the icon", based upon the information you've provided.